# How flexible is subsonic

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, subsonic, components

I currently use nhibernate but a guy at work has recently gotten me interested in subsonic again.  I really prefer a Poco, domain-driven style approach to development and worry about the database later.  It looks like this is partially supported using simplerepository.  My question is, how flexible is subsonic in how it generates your database ?  For example, nhibernate supports all 3 different types of inheritance mappings and components.  Components for those of you not familiar w/ NH, let you change how a class is stored in a table. So if you have a customer and address classes, in one situation you store the address in its own table and linked thru a foreign key, in another situation the address can be stored as part of the customer table.

Does subsonic give you these kind of options?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/subsonic-vs-nhibernate

Answer (score 1):

> Does subsonic give you these kind of options?

In a word, no. SubSonic really doesn't have the flexibility of nhibernate, the payoff is that it also doesn't have the complexity or the rather brutal learning curve. If you really need the inheritance mapping flexibility of nhibernate then you won't get it with SubSonic. The only question then is whether you actually need it, I've found I can almost always do without it.